# idiomatic way to enumerate NSArray by both index and element

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, enumeration

I need to do something similar to python's `enumerate()` function with an `NSArray` in `iOS` (I have to build NSIndexPath objects as well as examine the object).

I don't see a built in method for doing something like this (i.e. no NSArray equivalent of NSDictionary's  enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock: method). Which leaves me with two general approaches I can think of.

```
for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < mySequence.count; index++) {
    MyElementType *element = mySequence[index];
    //
    // code that works with both index and element
    //
}
```

or

```
NSUInteger index = 0;
for (MyElementType *element in mySequence) {
    //
    // code that works with both index and element
    //
    index++;
}
```

Is there a good reason to prefer on or the other? Or is there a third approach that is better than either of these?

Comment: I don't know who is up voting this, because it doesn't show any research. A perusal of the NSArray class reference would have turned up the answer in less time than it took to write this question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is following API present in NSArray:

```
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))
```

Comment: Headslap. I got deceived by the "Tasks" categories in the docs. In NSDictionary, there's a group of methods under `Enumerating Dictionaries`. I didn't think to look under `Sending Messages to Elements`. I figured that was just for the family of `makeObjectsPerform...` methods.